# Octal escape sequences are not allowed in template strings

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-builder, vue-cli-3

I'm building a desktop app using **electron** and vue, things went normal running the app in dev mode and building it untill the last building by running `electron:build` but I keep getting this error of **Octal escape sequences**.

I am pretty sure that it has to deal with the `strict mode`, but I tried to find the ocatal escapes but no chance, I tried to remove some useless dependencies the I added after the last successful build also didn't work

---

PS: the **electron:serve** works fine

**err picture**

[image]

> background.js from Terser
>   Octal escape sequences are not allowed in template strings 
>   [background.js:1026,68555]
>
> ERROR  Build failed with errors.
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! keyboard-managment@0.1.0 electron:build: `vue-cli-service electron:build`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the keyboard-managment@0.1.0 electron:build script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is in background.js. In lines 1026 and 68555, look for a template string with an octal sequence in it. Example:

```js
console.log(`Octal sequences like \033 are not allowed here`)
```

You can revert the es6 template to a (regular) string instead:

```js
console.log("Octal sequences like \033 are allowed here")
```

Or you might try a [different, permitted encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#ES2016_behavior), e.g.,

```js
console.log(`Sequences like \2264 are not allowed here`);
console.log(`But sequences like \u2264 are allowed`);
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this is a rather late response, but there is in fact a way to use octal escape sequences in template strings. You add the octal sequence using a normal string inside it. For example:

```
let myString = `foo ${"\033"} bar`
```

This is similar to adding the strings together:

```
let myString = `foo ` + "\003" + ` bar`
```

Answer (score 1):

I landed here when trying to change terminal output while in Typescript and `strict` mode. None of the above answers really covered it.

The original Javascript template string used the octal escape `\033`:

```js
`${info.timestamp} [${info.level}] \033[35m${info.label}\033[39m: ${info.message}`
```

However, these are deprecated when in strict mode. So the solution is to convert into a hexadecimal escape sequence instead:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal

This means you have to do the octal-to-hexadecimal conversion and turn `\033` into `\x1B` like so:

```js
`${info.timestamp} [${info.level}] \x1B[35m${info.label}\x1B[39m: ${info.message}`
```

This way the output of `info.label` in this example is color-coded as expected in a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(String.raw `Octal sequences like \033 are not allowed here`)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, change the backslashes into forward slashes

Comment: This was exactly the answer I needed. I had copied a log output from a java app, and wanted to analyze it using js, but it had all the paths as `\path\to\file\` which threw the octal error. This was a simple elegant solution that saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score -2):

As pointed out in [the section on ES2016 behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#es2016_behavior), octal strings work fine when started by `\0o` rather than `\0`:

This does *not* work:

```
console.log(`\033]0;Some title\007`);
```

but this *does*:

```
console.log(`\0o33]0;Some title\0o07`);
```

and has the desired effect of setting the terminal title.