# Javascript - replace a word within a string unless that word is contained within quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, text

I am writing some code that parses some SQL expressions, but have run into a problem I cannot solve on my own.  I want to replace a certain word in a SQL statement but not if that word is contained within a phrase that is enclosed in single or double quotes.  My use case is SQL expression parsing but I think this is more a generic string replacement thing.

To take an example consider the expression:
`select {foo} from Table where {foo} = "This is {foo} today" or {foo} = 'this is {foo} tomorrrow'  or {foo} = "it's all '{foo}' to me!"`

Assuming I want to replace `{foo}` to the string `bar`, the output would be:
`select bar from Table where bar = "This is {foo} today" or bar = 'this is {foo} tomorrow'  or bar = "it's all '{foo}' to me!"`

As we can see all `{foo}` expressions enclosed within quotes (single or double) have not been replaced.

We can make the assumption that quotes will be closed, i.e. there will be no stray quotes floating around (`where {foo} = 'un'even"` is not a use case we need to consider.)

Text within nested quotes should not be replaced (as however you look at it the text is contained within quotes :) )  The example shows an example of this in the `or {foo} = "it's all '{foo}' to me!"` part (as well as containing three single quotes just for fun)

I have done quite a bit of research on this and it seems a tricky thing to do in Javascript (or any other language no doubt).  This seems a good fit for regex, but any javascript solution regex or not would be helpful.  The closest I have come in Stack Overflow to a solution is [Don't replace regex if it is enclosed by a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683128/dont-replace-regex-if-it-is-enclosed-by-a-character) but it isn't a close enough match to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example string using JavaScript, you might use a single pattern with a callback a capture group to check for.

```
(['"]).*?\1|({foo})
```

The pattern matches:

- `(['"])` Group 1, capture either `"` or `'`
- `.*?` Match any char, as few as possible
- `\1` Match the same char as captured in group 1
- `|` Or
- `({foo})` Capture `{foo}` in group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EcJVpW/1)

In the callback check for group 2. If it is there, return it else return the whole match.

```js
const regex = /(['"]).*?\1|({foo})/g;
const str = `select {foo} from Table where {foo} = "This is {foo} today" or {foo} = 'this is {foo} tomorrrow'  or {foo} = "it's all '{foo}' to me!"`;
const result = str.replace(regex, (m, _, g2) => g2 ? "bar" : m);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you this does answer the question.  However when I try to make the {foo} dynamic by doing const regex = new RegExp(````(['"]).*?\1|({foo})````,'g') I get an error (in nodejs) as `Octal escape sequences are not allowed in template strings`.  any ideas why?  Or another way I could do this dynamically?  I can ask another question if needed

Comment: @kiwichris See this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039567/octal-escape-sequences-are-not-allowed-in-template-strings

Comment: thanks, but the link wasn't that relivant.  I played around a bit and it was the `\1` that was confusing node into thinking it was an octal escape sequence.  So I escaped it, giving 
  const regex = new RegExp(`(['"]).*?\\1|({ContactName})`,'g') and it seems to be working now :)

(note: stack overflow is interpreting my backticks as code symbols making things a bit confusing)

Comment: @kiwichris Yes if you use the RegExp constructor you have to double escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a regex replacement on `'.+?'|\{foo\}`, using a callback, and only make a replacement in the latter match.  Note that string literals in SQL use *single* quotes, not double quotes.  I will therefore refactor your query to use only single quotes for strings.

```js
var sql = "select {foo} from Table where {foo} = 'This is {foo} today' or {foo} = 'this is {foo} tomorrrow'  or {foo} = 'it''s all ''{foo}'' to me!'";
var output = sql.replace(/'.+?'|\{foo\}/g, (x) => x.match(/^\{.*\}$/) ? "bar" : x);
console.log(output);
```

Notes:

- The regex pattern tries to match terms in single quotes *first*, which ensures that we only match `{foo}` not in a string literal.
- A literal single quote in SQL is formed by doubling them up `''`

Comment: To be precise this is PartiQL which does seem to allow double quotes

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it could be done with a unique regular expression directly on your specific example since it's possible to have single quotes alone, interlaced single or double quotes, conflict of precedence etc. The best way according to me is to code a simple naive solution that works for most of your very use cases and then see if there's rooom for optimisation.

Something like the following in Javascript is working even if not really optimal (e.g. a replace with a callback could be less readible but morce concise):

```js
const source = `select {foo} from Table where {foo} = "This is {foo} today" or {foo} = 'this is {foo} tomorrow'  or {foo} = "it's all '{foo}' to me!"`;
const solution = `select bar from Table where bar = "This is {foo} today" or bar = 'this is {foo} tomorrow'  or bar = "it's all '{foo}' to me!"`;

const exclusions = [];
const exclusionPatterns = [/\".*?\"/g, /\'.*?\'/g];
let modifiedSource = source;

for (const pattern of exclusionPatterns) {
  let matches;
  while (true) {
    matches = modifiedSource.match(pattern);
    if (!matches) {
      break;
    }
    const firstMatch = matches[0];
    modifiedSource = modifiedSource.replace(
      firstMatch,
      `$${exclusions.length}`
    );
    exclusions.push(firstMatch);
  }
}

const destination = modifiedSource.replace(/(\{foo\})+/g, "bar");
let modifiedDestination = destination;

for (const [index, exclusion] of exclusions.entries()) {
  modifiedDestination = modifiedDestination.replace(`$${index}`, exclusion);
}

console.log(source);
console.log(modifiedSource);
console.log(modifiedDestination);
console.log(solution);
```